# VB.net search button

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I was working on this search button and I've manage to make it work. The only down side to this is when I try to search for a different item it keeps on putting back the old one I've searched for. What could be the problem?

Here's the code:

```
 Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    com.Connection = con
    com.CommandText = ("Select Student_ID from Student where Student_ID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'")
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Student"

    OpenDB()
    Dim SurName As String = ""
    Dim MiddleName As String = ""
    Dim FirstName As String = ""
    Dim SAddress As String = ""
    Dim Birthday As String = ""
    Dim Age As String = ""
    Dim Birthplace As String = ""
    Dim SContactNumber As String = ""
    Dim GradeYear As String = ""
    Dim SchoolYear As String = ""
    Dim ParentGaurdian As String = ""
    Dim PGContact As String = ""
    Dim PGAddress As String = ""
    rdr = com.ExecuteReader

    If rdr.Read = True Then
        SurName = rdr("StudentLastName").ToString
        MiddleName = rdr("StudentMiddleName").ToString
        FirstName = rdr("StudentFirstName").ToString
        SAddress = rdr("StudentAddress").ToString
        Birthday = rdr("Birthday").ToString
        Age = rdr("Age").ToString
        Birthplace = rdr("BirthPlace").ToString
        SContactNumber = rdr("StudentContactNumber").ToString
        GradeYear = rdr("GradeYearLevel").ToString
        SchoolYear = rdr("SchoolYear").ToString
        ParentGaurdian = rdr("ParentName").ToString
        PGContact = rdr("ParentContactNumber").ToString
        PGAddress = rdr("ParentAddress").ToString
    End If

    con.Close()
    com.Dispose()
    rdr.Close()

    txtSurName.Text = SurName
    txtMiddleName.Text = MiddleName
    txtFirstName.Text = FirstName
    txtSAddress.Text = SAddress
    txtBirthday.Text = Birthday
    txtAge.Text = Age
    txtBirthplace.Text = Birthplace
    txtSContactNumber.Text = SContactNumber
    txtGradeYear.Text = GradeYear
    txtSchoolYear.Text = SchoolYear
    txtParentGaurdian.Text = ParentGaurdian
    txtPGContact.Text = PGContact
    txtPGAddress.Text = PGAddress
End Sub
```

I've tried to play around with the rdr.close because I think that's the thing I've placed wrong.

Comment: There are several things wrong but you dont need to hop scotch data thru variables like that.  `txtSurName.Text = rdr("StudentLastName").ToString()` will work dandy.  I dont think anything is getting "put back" your SQL is messed up.  `"SELECT * FROM Student"` grabs them all and doesnt search at all - it is replacing the better query just above it.  Also use SQL PArameters and DIspose of DBObjects

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your SQL query should be more like this:

```
'com.CommandText = ("Select Student_ID from Student where Student_ID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'")
'com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Student"
com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Student_ID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
```

Comment: Not my DV but SQL should never use concatenation.

Comment: I agree about not concatenating SQL, but this isn't a question about best practice. I'm pretty sure my answer addresses the problem and resolves it with minimal change to the poster's original code.

Comment: SO answers are for the Ages - the many to come looking in the future - an answer which says `your SQL should be like this:...` then concats the query is giving bad advice.

Comment: Point taken. When looking for answers, I always favour the concise, but your comment is appreciated @Plutonix - I'm pretty new to this and you have a wealth of SO experience. I will keep your advice in mind for the future

Answer (score 0):

Remove below two lines..

```
com.CommandText = ("Select Student_ID from Student where Student_ID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'")
com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Student"
```

And instead use below..

```
com.CommandText = ("Select Student_ID from Student where Student_ID = @searchText")
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchText", txtSearch.Text)
```